# for loop in R - generate different graphics

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, graph, lm

If I have a set of data for different samples (x) and a fixed y, like:

```
> x1 <- c(5,6,7,8)
> x2 <- c(9,7.8,6,8)
> x3 <- c(7,3,5,1)x 
> y <- c(20,21,20,50)
```

If I want to try to plot these data like (x1 ~ y), (x2 ~ y), (x3 ~ y)

```
> x_data <- data_frame(x1, x2, x3)
> 
> for (i in seq_along(x_data)) {   
>   model <- lm(x_data[i] ~ y)
>   plot(model) 
> }
```

However, this is not working and I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x_data[i] ~ y, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'x_data')
```

I am trying to picture them to check if there is a dependency on the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the formula with `paste`

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))
for (i in seq_along(x_data)) {   
    model <- lm(as.formula(paste(names(x_data)[i],  "~ y")), data = x_data)
      plot(model) 
     }
```

[image]

---

or with `reformulate`

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))
for (i in seq_along(x_data)) {   
    model <- lm(reformulate("y", response = names(x_data)[i]), data = x_data)
      plot(model) 
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply! Both answers worked perfectly! Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: @Harr1ls `reformulate` is more compact, but `paste` may be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Consider `reformulate` and binding all vectors into a data frame to use with `data` argument of `lm`:

```r
model_data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

# ITERATE ACROSS COLUMN NAMES, IGNORING FIRST
for (x in colnames(model_data[-1])) {   
  model <- lm(reformulate("y", response=x), data=model_data)
  plot(model) 
}
```